# Admin product and order pages: search all fields

Tags: admin, search

In the Magento Admin I can search products by their name and SKU and different other values. I can add more colums to the grid using special modules, and then I can use those columns for searching as well. I think this is too limited.

Is there a module that can search on all product fields, including the custom attributes? The same goes for orders and possibly other admin pages.

Answer (score 2):

Try the "Global Record Search" at the top of all Magento admin pages.

Comment: That does not search through every attribute. Just the ones marked in the backend as "Used in search". It also searches the orders but only `increment_id`, and shipping and billing addresses firstname, lastname phone and zipcode. It also searches the customers but only firstname, lastname and company.

Comment: That is actually very useful. I've never used that field. Still I would like to know if there is something better than that?

Comment: Global Search Not return by Order, if i enter order id it is not return anything, how can i configure to get my order by using order id.

Answer (score 2):

Because of Magento EAV design it would be extremely slow to do a search on every field, however you could create your own module that plug into Global Record Search

Take a look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Search_Customer`

In your config.xml

```
...
<adminhtml>
    ...
    <global_search>
        <matt_car_test>
            <class>matt_car/search_test</class>
            <acl>matt_car</acl>
        </matt_car_test>
    </global_search>
    ...
</adminhtml>
```

Read more at [Adding your custom module to Magento’s Admin Global Search](http://blog.mattstephens.co.uk/post/27326981315/adding-custom-module-to-magentos-admin-global-search)

You could also rewrite the default search and add your custom fields

```
<global>
    <models>
        .......
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <search_customer>MagePal_AdvanceGlobalSearch_Adminhtml_Model_Search_Customer</search_customer>
                <search_order>MagePal_AdvanceGlobalSearch_Adminhtml_Model_Search_Order</search_order>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>       
    </models>
</global>
```